# mysql when UNION display [Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

I do a sql oj on hackerrank. I need to first order people with name and order occupation with corresponding count. Database table like the png image display [table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22u1c.png).
I want to use

```
select type from
(
(
SELECT name as type, 1 as filter FROM occupations
order by name
)
UNION All
(
select concat(count(occupation), ' ', lower(occupation), 's.') as type, 2 as filter
FROM occupations
group by occupation 
order by count(occupation)
)
) result
order by filter, type
```

to solve this question, but get "[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function".
If I comment order by count(occupation) could be okay. Or just use

```
select concat(count(occupation), ' ', lower(occupation), 's.') as type, 2 as filter
FROM occupations
group by occupation 
order by count(occupation)
```

is also okay, but once union would receive this error

```
(
SELECT name as type, 1 as filter FROM occupations
order by name
)
UNION All

(
select concat(count(occupation), ' ', lower(occupation), 's.') as type, 2 as filter
FROM occupations
group by occupation 
order by count(occupation)
)
```

but I copy this union to postgresql(change string contract function) is okay, no this error.[postgresql is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4ij7.png)
In mysql, I must to convert this "order by count(occupation)" set to another temporary table to solve this error, like this:

```
select type from 
(
    (SELECT concat(name, '(', LEFT(occupation , 1), ')') as type, 1 as filter FROM occupations
    order by name)
UNION All
    (select * from 
        (
        select concat('There are a total of ', count(occupation), ' ', lower(occupation), 's.') as type, 2 as filter
        FROM occupations
        group by occupation 
        order by count(occupation)
        ) 
    result)
) last 
order by filter, type
```

I am very confused, very appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order by` is invalid within unions. Move the `order by` outside of the union operation.

Comment: but why there in unions order by name is okay, but order by count(occupation) cause error, even though the order is no sense， union would reorder the table